# Best way to make a bootable WIndows 10 image on USB with all existing softwares, drivers & configurations to deploy on identical hardwares?

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, bootable-media, licensing

Best way to make a bootable Windows 10 image on USB with all existing software, drivers & configurations to deploy on exactly identical hardware?

There is no difference in the hardware we want to deploy that image on.

Planning to deploy this image on over 4000 desktops of same hardware configuration and make and model.

Is there a freeware/opensource/free software that we can use for this purpose commercially?

can you suggest a solution and KB article where it's step by step explained how to achieve it or do it?

Comment: Google: sysprep for windows 10

Comment: @moab sysprep not found in windows 10 pro version

Comment: https://www.petri.com/using-syspre-windows-10

Answer (score -1):

Open control panel > Backup and restore > Create a system image > Follow the wizard.

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-make-full-backup-windows-10

I wonder if there is a way to deploy windows installation through the LAN(ethernet) network all at once instead of using a USB one by one.Comment if anybody knows.